# Tile Random Tensor Without Loosing Randomness in TensorFlow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

In the following example I have a random row tensor `r` (which for the sake of the example is a simple `tf.random_normal` but in my real code is a complicated graph instead, whose shape I cannot change).

It seems like that in TensorFlow the `tf.tile` operation is run only after the value of `r` is computed, indeed all the rows of the tiled tensor `t` are the same. Is there a way to tile a tensor without loosing the randomness of each tile?

```
import tensorflow as tf

r = tf.random_normal(shape=[1, 2])

t = tf.tile(r, tf.pack([3, 1]), name=None)

session = tf.Session()

print(session.run(t))

session.close()
```

Result (all row the same):

```
[[ 0.29335016  0.11843499]
 [ 0.29335016  0.11843499]
 [ 0.29335016  0.11843499]]
```

Desired result (all rows computed separately):

```
[[ 0.29335016  0.11843499]
 [ 0.46995060  0.58384848]
 [ 0.73958005  0.95689274]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You get all rows as same because `tf.tile` does replication of the first argument. In your case, the node named `r` outputs a random tensor. This tensor is fed to `tf.tile` which replicates it (i.e copies the value) three times.

If you do not want that you can directly pass a specified shape to `tf.random_normal()` to generate a tensor which is entirely random and matches your shape requirement.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure that I understand. I don't want to do shuffling. I just have a random row tensor and I want to stack it in a matrix, but as soon as I do that all the rows are the same. Ideally each row should be computed separately and be "random". Is there any operation I can use to achieve this instead of tf.tile?

Comment: Modified my answer after better understanding your query.

Comment: Thanks for modifying your answer. As I said though tf.random_normal is just an example. Would it still be possible to achieve the same with a random tensor that has a fixed shape?

Comment: If you have a random tensor with a fixed shape, and you want it to get tiled with randomness, you will have to follow my previous approach i.e applying `tf.random_shuffle` over it. If you want rows to be random then you must transpose it before that.

Comment: `tf.random_shuffle` just shuffles the values computed by my tensor, it does not generate new values using my random tensor... so all the values in each row of the tiled tensor would just be the same but shuffled, is that correct? If so this is still not what I need.

Comment: It seems that you need to rephrase and edit your question in a very clear and purposeful manner. You mention about tiling the tensor and not loosing randomness and now you are talking about generating new values using a random tensor. 
It is tough to help without a clear and purposeful question definition.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not very clear. I've added a "Desired result" example to show what I'm trying to do. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: You can easily achieve this by specifying shape=(3,2) in `tf.random_normal()`.

Comment: As I said `tf.random_normal()` is just an example, ignore this detail please, and consider a generic random tensor instead.

Comment: I think you are very confused. Let me say that a function outputs a random tensor of shape (7,5). What would you like to do with this tensor ?

Comment: If you read my question it should be clear what I want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136728/discussion-between-ujjwal-and-njk).